# Check macOS update available using Swift on macOS

Tags: swift, macos

I am currently building a `macOS` App that checks if a predefined minimum `macOS` version is installed e.g. `10.14.3` and if not does something.

Is there any chance to force a check os update and get the result out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the terminal app, you can check for new software updates with the `software update -l` command. You can execute commands with the Process class in the Foundation framework, and parse the text output. It is also possible to configure the command line tool with some parameters. Look into the softwareupdate command and the Process class in Foundation. I am not sure this is allowed, if you plan on submitting the app to the App Store.